Cannot install xanmod kennel in 22.04
After I run the install in the last is said:
dpkg: error processing package linux-xanmod-x64v3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.12.6-x64v3-xanmod1
 linux-xanmod-x64v3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

